# org.hibernate.QueryException: JPA-style positional param was not an integral ordinal

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql

I have the following JPQL request;

```
@Query(value = "select req_t " +
        "from TransactionRelation tr " +
        "inner join tr.requestTransaction req_t " +
        "inner join req_t.transactionStateHistory req_t_h " +
        "inner join tr.responseTransaction resp_t " +
        "inner join resp_t.transactionStateHistory resp_t_h " +
        "where req_t.id >?1 " +
        "and req_t.receiver.id=?2 and req_t.requestType in ?3" +
        "and NOT EXISTS (select t from resp_t_h t where t.transactionState = 'REPLIED' )" +
        "and EXISTS (select tt from req_t_h tt where tt.transactionState = 'WAITING_PROVIDER' )"
)
List<Transaction> queryTrabsactions(Long transactionId, Long providerId, Collection<RequestType> requestTypes);
```

But it prints following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.finvale.repositories.TransactionRepository.queryTransactions(java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long,java.util.Collection)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:72) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:53) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:212) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: JPA-style positional param was not an integral ordinal
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:131) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:663) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: JPA-style positional param was not an integral ordinal
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterParser.parse(ParameterParser.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParamLocationRecognizer.parseLocations(ParamLocationRecognizer.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.buildParameterMetadata(HQLQueryPlan.java:381) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:546) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:655) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    ... 68 common frames omitted
```

What the reason of my problem?

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you use the approach described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters, it is much less error-prone

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You have no whitespace between lines

```
"and req_t.receiver.id=?2 and req_t.requestType in ?3" +
    "and NOT EXISTS
```

also check that the ?3 param is not empty list

Answer (score 68):

It happened to me, I had a ' ; ' char at the end of my query, copy pasted from my database querying tool :

```
@Query(value = " DELETE FROM reunion WHERE id = ?1; ", nativeQuery = true)
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it was me having no space between my param AND operator. This happened because I had my query on 2 lines of code