# QueryException: JPA-style positional param was not an integral ordinal

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot

I got "QueryException: JPA-style positional param was not an integral ordinal"
I try to solve by the way others solve such as [org.hibernate.QueryException: JPA-style positional param was not an integral ordinal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114250/org-hibernate-queryexception-jpa-style-positional-param-was-not-an-integral-ord) but it still doesn't work.

I  try to hardcode change form ?1 to some data that already have in the database and it works but after change to ?1 it gives an error again.

--- Before Hardcode (have Error)
-- In Repository --

```
@Query(
    value = "SELECT user_att_workshop.id, user_att_workshop.user_id, user_att_workshop.workshop_att_id, skill.skill_name, user_att_workshop.skill_score " + 
            "FROM user_att_workshop LEFT JOIN skill on user_att_workshop.skill_id = skill.id " + 
            "WHERE user_att_workshop.user_id = ?1 " + 
            "AND user_att_workshop.workshop_att_id = ?2;", 
            nativeQuery = true
)
public List<UserScoreByWorkshopAtt> findUserScoreByUserIdAndWorkshopId(int userId, int workshopId);
```

-- In Service --

```
public List<UserScoreByWorkshopAtt> findUserScoreByUserIdAndWorkshopIdtest(
    int userId, 
    int workshopId) {

    return 
        userScoreByWorkshopAttRepository.findUserScoreByUserIdAndWorkshopId(
        userId,
        workshopId
    );
}
```

-- In controller --

```
List<UserScoreByWorkshopAtt> getUserScooreByUserId(
    @PathVariable("user_id") int userId, 
    @PathVariable("workshop_id") int workshopId) {

    return userScoreByWorkshopAttService.findUserScoreByUserIdAndWorkshopIdtest(
        userId, 
        workshopId
    );

}
```

--- After Hardcode (can run and have no error)
-- In Repository --

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT user_att_workshop.id, user_att_workshop.user_id, user_att_workshop.workshop_att_id, skill.skill_name, user_att_workshop.skill_score FROM user_att_workshop LEFT JOIN skill on user_att_workshop.skill_id = skill.id  WHERE user_att_workshop.user_id = 5 AND user_att_workshop.workshop_att_id = 2;", nativeQuery = true)
public List<UserScoreByWorkshopAtt> findUserScoreByUserIdAndWorkshopId();
```

-- In Service --

```
public List<UserScoreByWorkshopAtt> findUserScoreByUserIdAndWorkshopIdtest() {
    return userScoreByWorkshopAttRepository.findUserScoreByUserIdAndWorkshopId();
}
```

-- In controller --

```
List<UserScoreByWorkshopAtt> getUserScooreByUserId(@PathVariable("user_id") int userId,
            @PathVariable("workshop_id") int workshopId) {
        return userScoreByWorkshopAttService.findUserScoreByUserIdAndWorkshopIdtest();
    }
```

> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: JPA-style positional param
>   was not an integral ordinal   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterParser.parse(ParameterParser.java:195)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParamLocationRecognizer.parseLocations(ParamLocationRecognizer.java:56)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.internal.NativeQueryInterpreterStandardImpl.getParameterMetadata(NativeQueryInterpreterStandardImpl.java:30)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getSQLParameterMetadata(QueryPlanCache.java:128)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getNativeQueryImplementor(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1000)
>     ... 85 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you write it as follows :

```
@Query(
    value = "SELECT user_att_workshop.id, user_att_workshop.user_id, user_att_workshop.workshop_att_id, skill.skill_name, user_att_workshop.skill_score " + 
            "FROM user_att_workshop LEFT JOIN skill on user_att_workshop.skill_id = skill.id " + 
            "WHERE user_att_workshop.user_id = :userId " + 
            "AND user_att_workshop.workshop_att_id = :workshopId;", 
            nativeQuery = true
)
public List<UserScoreByWorkshopAtt> findUserScoreByUserIdAndWorkshopId(@Param("userId")int userId,@Param("workshopId") int workshopId);
```

OR remove the `';'` from end of the query and check for any whitespace

```
@Query(
    value = "SELECT user_att_workshop.id, user_att_workshop.user_id, user_att_workshop.workshop_att_id, skill.skill_name, user_att_workshop.skill_score " + 
            "FROM user_att_workshop LEFT JOIN skill on user_att_workshop.skill_id = skill.id " + 
            "WHERE user_att_workshop.user_id =?1 " + 
            "AND user_att_workshop.workshop_att_id =?2", 
            nativeQuery = true
)
public List<UserScoreByWorkshopAtt> findUserScoreByUserIdAndWorkshopId(int userId, int workshopId);
```