# Wrap double quotes across native query parameter in Spring data jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have to run the following Oracle query using Spring Data JPA native queries.

```
create user "kshitij" identified by "qwert123"
```

I am trying this :

```
@Query(value="create user \"?1\" identified by \"qwert123\"",nativeQuery=true)
    void createUser(String userName);
```

However when I wrap ?1 by "" then it Hibernate stops treating ?1 as variable to be substituted by userName, instead as actual string. 
How would I accomplish running the above mentioned Oracle query in spring data jpa?

Alongwith create I would also like to check if user exists.

Current not working approach :

```
@Query(value="select username from all_users where username = \"?1\"", nativeQuery=true)
```

Comment: Either use @Rohan Shah's answer or remove the double quotes around `?1`. Replace your query by `@Query(value="create user ?1 identified by \"qwert123\"",nativeQuery=true)
    void createUser(String userName);`
Also, add the `@Modifying` modifier.

Comment: why you want double quote "" ......  it can be CREATE USER myuser IDENTIFIED BY password

Comment: you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56310935/queryexception-jpa-style-positional-param-was-not-an-integral-ordinal/56315857#56315857

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use parameters? There is an annotation for telling the native queries what the parameters are and it is like this,

```
@Query(value="create user :userName identified by \"qwert123\"",nativeQuery=true)
    void createUser(@Param("userName")String userName);
```

Comment: Using that will give out the same issue as ?1 since after wrapping :userName in quotes, ie ":userName" it again becomes a string literal. What I want to accomplish is have variable getting substituted alongwith quote wrapping around them.

Comment: But he wants quotes in his Query @SternK

Comment: If I don't wrap the parameter in quotes I'm running into the following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59409574/parameterized-queries-to-create-a-user-throwing-missing-user-or-role-name-except

Answer (score 0):

Can you try usiig this code?

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value="create user :userName identified by \"qwert123\"",nativeQuery=true)
void createUser(@Param("userName") String userName);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quiet easy, but I also needed some time to figure it out!

When you are using postgres, there's a function provided to achieve double quotes (there is also one for single quotes). The JPA-Native-Query will execute it on the parameter-value!

```html
quote_ident(:param)
```

This works with named query parameters. Haven't tried it yet with unnamed, but that doesn't make a huge difference at all!

Answer (score -1):

Place this on top of class or entity.

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "EntityName.getUserName", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username = :username")
})
```

[Named Query](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/ent30qry001.htm)

Comment: How would solve this issue? The query wold still run without the double quotes surrounded on it. From what I have observed when spring data jpa replaces params and generates query on the fly it treats the param surrounded by single quoes. This would work in case of select * where query, but for create user / drop user query this is an invalid oracle query, running it directly on Oracle fails too, that's why it is important for me to enclose them in double quotes.

Comment: Are you setting a parameter value username?